# On the field vs in the field

Tags: prepositions

I had seen here that in a field is in an open, grass field and on the field is on a sports field. Eg "The horses are in the field." "The players are on the field." But then I saw on a test, "We run in parks and in sports fields, but we don'tgo in tennis or baseball courts." Shouldn't it be on sports fields and on tennis and baseball courts?
Is it in because it's running?

I suppose this "go" means "run"?

This was the audio recording, supposedly an American talking.

Comment: I suppose **in** is used when thinking of the field as an enclosed area, **on** when it's a surface for playing on. I don't know about baseball, but we say '**on** a tennis court'.

Comment: @KateBunting  In baseball, we say "on the field" too.  It's interesting; I would say flowers grow in the/a field, or dogs are running around in the/a field, but when *field* means "a specific place of sport", it's always *on*.

Comment: **Go** doesn't mean "run", it just means...*go*, the same as in "Go to the end of the line", or "Don't go in the house."  If someone used it to mean "run", that is an error.

Answer (score 1):

The correct sentence should be,

> We run in parks and **on** sports fields, but we don't go **to** tennis or baseball courts.

In this case you can run *in* parks and *on* sports field, and you **go** to a tennis/baseball court, you cannot go **in** though. It's "in" because its going in something, and "on" because you are running on a surface.

Comment: NOT CORRECT: go "in" tennis/basketball courts.  CORRECT: go "to" tennis/basketball courts. Please edit your answer.

Comment: @PPH thanks I have edited my answer, is it ok now?